# Optimized way to check for authentication in Next + nextauth

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth, t3

What would be the best way to check for auth and show the user a login component using next auth.

Would you rather redirect the user to a login page or just render a login component instead of the component that the user is querying.

Not sure if it makes a difference but trying to write clean code. Or maybe you can think of another better option ?

```
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react"

export default function Component() {
  const { data: session } = useSession()
  if(session) {
    return <>
      Component
    </>
  }
    //Redirect OR render login component.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably most professional way would be redirecting, I would choose that option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).